# Ошибка выделения памяти для char**

Tags: c, malloc

Собственно, вопрос в чем:

Почему код вида:

```
char *r = (char *)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
```

выполняется без ошибок, то есть память выделяется нормально, а вот в коде:

```
char **r = (char **)malloc(5 * sizeof(char *));
```

я вижу в значении переменной **r** следующее -

```
0xbaadf00d <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xbaadf00d>
```

Почему так? Для массива символов все нормально выделяется, а для массива указателей нет?

**UPD** : Похожее выделение памяти для массива указателей в другой функции работает нормально.

**UPD2**: значение `r` отслеживается через отладчик.

Comment: Как вы это (значение `r`) видите? `printf("%p\n",r)`?

Comment: Проблема не с выделением памяти. Проблема с тем, как эта память потом используется. В вопросе релевантного кода нет.

Comment: @D-side На то и намекаю... Скорее всего, выполняется какое-то обращение типа `**r`.

Comment: @Harry нет никакого `обращение типа **r`, значение `r` вижу через отладчик.

Comment: Нам нужен способ воспроизвести проблему, чтобы понять, в чём она заключается. В идеале, подготовьте пример, который показывает эту же проблему **без** отладчика. Или хотя бы расскажите, в каком состоянии отладчик в этот момент, какие строчки прошёл и где остановился.

Comment: @АлександрОнищук отладчик может как-то не так интерпретировать указатель и писать всякую ересь. Попробуйте заменить `char` на `void` во втором случае.

Comment: @D-side возмите код из вопроса, загоните в функцию main, вот вам и будет исключение

Comment: @alexolut не может, включено отображение по адресам в памяти

Comment: [Всё нормально](http://ideone.com/GQ3W7w), не падает.

Comment: второй пример выделяет память под 5 указателей на `char*` (да, указатель на указатели). Но в тех 20 байтах (5 * 4) записан мусор. Но вот отладчик о них то ещё не знает. и попытка прочитать по этим адресам печальна. Более того baadfood как бы намекает.

Comment: `void main()
{
    char **r = (char **)malloc(5 * sizeof(char *));
    printf("%p\n",r);
}`
Компилируется, выводит что-то типа `0041E050`... Что надо сделать для падения?

Comment: Проинициализировать первую строку 0x0 :) Мой промах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем все оказалось проще некуда:

- инициализация действительно проходила успешно
- после чего выделялась память для  первого элемента
- в этот первый элемент приходила строка из структуры данных

И вот эта самая строка из структуры приходила с адресом 0x0. 
Функция на получение структуры данных написана не мной, поэтому я не сразу заподозрил точное место ошибки. Простите все те, кому я не поверил

Всем спасибо.